# rules:changes always evaluates as true in MR pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a monorepo where each package should be built as a docker image.

I created a trigger job for each package that triggers a child pipeline.

In the MR, my changes rule is being ignored and all child pipelines are triggered.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
---
workflow:
  rules:
     - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID || $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

trigger-package-a:
  stage: build
  trigger:
    include: .gitlab/ci/packages/package-gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  rules:
   - changes:
      - "packages/package-a/**/*"
  variables:
    PACKAGE: package-a

trigger-package-b:
  stage: build
  trigger:
    include: .gitlab/ci/packages/package-gitlab-ci.yml
    strategy: depend
  rules:
    - changes:
      - "packages/package-b/**/*"
  variables:
    PACKAGE: package-b

done_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - "echo DONE"
    - "cat config.json"
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
```

**package-gitlab-ci.yml**

```
workflow:
   rules:
     - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
     - changes:
         - "packages/${PACKAGE}/**/*"

stages:
  - bootstrap
  - validate

cache:
  key: "${PACKAGE}_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
  paths:
    - packages/${PACKAGE}/node_modules/
  policy: pull

install-package:
  stage: bootstrap
  script:
    - echo ${PACKAGE}}
    - echo '{"package":${PACKAGE}}' > config.json
    - "cd packages/${PACKAGE}/"
    - yarn install --frozen-lockfile
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - config.json
  cache:
    key: "${PACKAGE}_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}"
    paths:
     - packages/${PACKAGE}/node_modules/
    policy: pull-push

lint-package:
  script:
   - yarn lint
  stage: validate
  needs: [install-package]
  before_script:
   - "cd packages/${PACKAGE}/"

test-package:
  stage: validate
  needs: [lint-package]
  before_script:
     - "echo working on ${PACKAGE}"
     - "cd packages/${PACKAGE}/"
  rules:
     - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
  script:
     -  yarn test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your downstream pipeline is defining a workflow with 2 independent rules: `if` and `changes`. This may cause the jobs to be included if the first condition in the `if` is met, i.e. if it is a MR pipeline. Try removing the dash in front of `changes`, as in the example [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges), to treat this as a single rule:

```yaml
workflow:
   rules:
     - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
       changes:
         - "packages/${PACKAGE}/**/*"
```

**EDIT:** This recent [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/335792) states `rules:changes` does not work as expected with `trigger`. So you may actually need to remove the `changes` from the upstream pipeline and solve this in the downstream pipeline.

Side note, not directly related to your issue: the [GitLab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/workflow.html#switch-between-branch-pipelines-and-merge-request-pipelines) provide a workflow template to run branch or MR pipelines without creating duplicates. You can use this in your upstream pipeline if it helps:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
```